# ChartJS v4 onwards, error prompted "Missing class properties transform"

Tags: reactjs, web, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Using React v17 and react-chartjs-2 v5.2.0

After 'npm i' with Chart.js v4.4 and react-chartjs-2 v5.2.0, start up the application and received the error "Missing class properties transform"

Does anyone knows what's the reason for the new Chart JS V4 error?

1. Downgrading to Chart.js v3.9.1 will resolve the issue but it will not be compatible with react-chartjs-2 v5.2.0
2. Tried different version of Chart.js v4, still get the same error.